# Div echo in array appears multiple times

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am getting an empty extra version of each div when this code runs as a Wordpress template. I can hide it with css div:empty {display: none;}
but I would like to know why this happens and how to fix my error.
   My output is

1. div read1-hold> booktitle    /div
2. div read2-hold>             /div
3. div read1-hold>              /div
4. div read2-hold">booktitle2  /div

```html
 
 <div id="primary" class="content-area">
  <main id="content" class="clearfix">
 
 
 <?php

$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array('read1','read2'),
    'post_status'            => 'publish',
    'pagination'             => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => 2,
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'orderby'                => 'title',
); 

?>

<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 


echo '<div class="read1-hold">';
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'book1_title', true);
echo '</div>';


echo '<div class="read2-hold">';
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'book2_title', true);
echo '</div>';

?>

<?php endwhile;?>  

</main>
      
 </div>
 

<?php get_footer();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting 'empty' book titles where there is no book2_title or book1_title for the post.

Try something like:

```
$title= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'book2_title', true);
if (!empty($title)) 
    echo '<div class="read1-hold">'.$title.'</div>';
```